# How do i use a background or image with fading edges on Android?

Tags: android, image, background, fade

I want to have a background with a smaller picture/background color on top, but I'd like to have the edges of the smaller picture/background have fading edges so it's not just a square shaped brick.

Here's the code I have with a background image on my FrameLayout and a white color on my LinearLayout inside of the Framelayout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.example.snake.LevelScoreActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:background="@drawable/snakebackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outputTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Level X Score" 
        android:textSize="14dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Username" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output2"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Score" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Timestamp" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outputNoScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="" 
        android:textSize="14dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: My first instinct would be a custom `GradientDrawable` with transparencies. But I'm not sure if that is possible with a `GradientDrawable`.

Comment: just simple custom BitmapDrawable will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You should fade your image directly in an image editor software, instead of doing it in your android app, instead the fade width depends on a variable...

Comment: Can you re-explain this? I don't quite understand.

Comment: If you just want your background image's edges to be faded, why don't you just fade it once, directly on your raw image, instead of doing this by code in android? Sorry for my english. I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

try this custom BitmapDrawable:

```
class BD extends BitmapDrawable {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mSrcInPaint;
    private int mRadius;
    private Rect mDrawRect;

    public BD(Resources res, Bitmap b, int radius) {
        super(res, b);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(radius, Blur.NORMAL));

        mSrcInPaint = new Paint();
        mSrcInPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        mRadius = radius;
        mDrawRect = new Rect();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        int cnt = canvas.saveLayer(null, null, Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
        mDrawRect.set(getBounds());
        mDrawRect.inset(mRadius, mRadius);
        canvas.drawRect(mDrawRect, mPaint);

        canvas.saveLayer(null, mSrcInPaint, Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(cnt);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I use this class to set the background of my linearlayout? I'm sorry if I don't fully understand, but I am quite new to Android.

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable

Comment: I know the command to set backgrounds for things, what I meant is, usually you put your picture for example `setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.blabl.png)`, but how do i use this method and use the "converted picture" as the paramter to setBackgroudndrawable?

Comment: no, setBackgroundDrawable takes Drawable as a parameter